# No idea how to exit source control in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I was trying to connect my Python files. Didn't go as planned and for some reason started source control without a clue how to get back.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone have a clue how I exit and just go back to normal?

Comment: Source Control isn't a mode, it's a panel. So what's the actual problem? It looks like you have a diff (*comparison*) open on the right, is that what you're talking about? Please [edit] to clarify. And what do you mean by "connect my Python files"? Put them into a source control system like Git?

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips.

Comment: Just in case it's relevant: you can click the Source Control button on the left to close the panel.

Comment: @wjandrea I was trying to connect some of my files to GitHub and now the source control and as you said a diff is open. I just see that I have pending changes on source control and all of my file names are in green.

Comment: OK, that all sounds normal, so what's the problem? Are you not familiar with the process for setting up a Git repo via VSCode?

Comment: Oh wait, did you initialize a Git repo without meaning to? What did you want to do instead?

Comment: @wjandrea The task was to pull from GitHub repo. I am not familiar with git repo via VSCode

Comment: OK, you can still do that. Have you set up the remote? If so, have you tried pulling yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have inadvertently clicked the `Initialize Repository` button. You can remove the source control by opening the directory in your File Manager and deleting the `.git` folder. That will remove the source control from your project.

If you want to go further, you can right click on the source control icon: [image: vscode source control icon] and then click `Hide 'Source Control'`.

Answer (score 10):

If you just want to turn off git related functions, you can use the following command on the command line(**ctrl+shift+P**):

```
Git: Close Repository
```

[image]

Then open your settings :

Change `Git: Auto Repository Detection` to **false**

[image]

Comment: This answer suits my case the most, hence an upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. **Open File Explorer or Finder:**

   - Navigate to the directory where you made the changes. Make sure you are in the right folder.
2. **Show Hidden Files:**

   - In the top bar, find the **VIEW** option.
   - Click on it, then select **Show** and check the **Hidden items** option. This will reveal hidden files.
3. **Locate and Delete .git and .vscode folders:**

   - Now that hidden files are visible, look for the **.git** and **.vscode** folders in the directory.
   - Delete both of these folders. Ensure that your Visual Studio Code application is closed before proceeding.
4. **Reopen Visual Studio Code:**

   - After deleting the folders, reopen Visual Studio Code.
   - Check if the problem is resolved. Your settings should now be back to default.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking to do is close the source control panel, you just need to click on the tab for it.
[image: Source control tab highlighted]

If you are trying to do something else you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: When I close the panel it still says "25 pending changes" when I hover over the source control icon and all my files are green for some reason