# Can someone tell me why I have pending changes from old projects in my new project in the source control tab in Vs code

Tags: github

I have 172 pending changes from my old project that I can see in my new project that I created.
What should I do to clear it? I want to push my new project to Github but cannot until I figure out what's happening as I don't want to effect any other projects I've worked on.

Has anyone else experiences this??

Answer (score 0):

Check if the command `Git: Close Repository` (as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577121/6309)) would work to close the old project repository.

Or try and open a new VSCode from the repository folder of your current new project: `code -n .`, and see if the issue persists then.